# How can I change the accessible name of the "OK" hamburger button in an app built from the Xamarin AppShell template?

Tags: xamarin, accessibility

I've built a Xamarin Android app based on the Xamarin AppShell template in VS. The hamburger button which invokes the flyout gets announced by the TalkBack screen reader as having a name of "OK". This doesn't seem a good match for the purpose of the button, perhaps a name of "Menu" would be more helpful. I've not found a way to change the AutomationProperties.Name of the hamburger button.

How can I change the hamburger button such that TalkBack announces it as the "Menu" button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Xamarin but with basic Android coding, you'd use `android:contentDescription` to specify the text you want the screen reader (Talkback) to announce.

`contentDescription` is also mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/accessibility

Answer (score 0):

In the Android, there is a property named toolbar.NavigationContentDescription for the hamburger button in the app shell. You can set it by a custom shell renderer.

custom shell renderer :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers

And set the property

```
 public class MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
    public MyShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(toolbar, toolbarTracker, appearance);
        // I had debug the value of description and it's "ok".
       // string description = toolbar.NavigationContentDescription;
        toolbar.NavigationContentDescription = "menu";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. Based on this, I created a custom ShellToolbarAppearanceTracker, but found that SetAppearance() didn't get called. As a test I set NavigationContentDescription in SetColors() which did get called, and the TalkBack screen reader then announced the button as "Menu" as required, so this is great!

Comment: Unfortunately if I then interact with the flyout to move between ContentPages, I found the button got reset to be "OK" after the switch. As a test I tried changing the toolbar's ContentDescription rather than the NavigationContentDescription, and found the ContentDescription didn't get reset after selecting from the flyout. So I'll continue investigating why the NavigationContentDescription did seem to get reset. Perhaps it's related to how I created the ShellSections in https://github.com/gbarkerz/MobileGridGames/blob/master/MobileGridGames/MobileGridGames/AppShell.xaml.cs.

Comment: I had test my demo and meet the same problem. And when I set the ContentDescription, it also got reset. So It may need to custom the toolbar in the android to set the NavigationContentDescription.